# Escape period in the creation of a new object instance

Tags: php

I have two php files, 1 file is a class, let's call it 'Class1.php', in the folder:

```
/example/folderX/folderY/
```

The other file is in the folder:

```
/example/folderZ/
```

The second file contains a function that creates an instance of the object in Class1.php like this:

```
 $Object = new ..\folderX\folderY\Class1($paramater);
```

This however does not work because of the periods to go back one directory.

I don't know how to escape these periods, the normal escaping procedure in php does not work. Can anyone help me with a way to escape the periods? Or is there maybe a better way to fix this? (Without changing the structure of my folders)

Comment: [Namespace](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.namespaces.php) the classes and perhaps do a composer style include?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Namespaces - go up a level?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245695/php-namespaces-go-up-a-level)

Answer (score 2):

You must include the file instead of using the path when instantiating the object:

```
require('../folderX/folderY/Class1.php');

$object = new Class1($parameter);
```